# Group By two tables and then JOIN them

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

**Table 1** with `PRIMARY KEY (campaign_id, type, keyword, report_date)`

| campaign_id | type | keyword | impressions | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | link | shower gel | 2 | 2021-05-01 |
| 1 | search engine | gel for body | 5 | 2021-05-01 |
| 1 | link | fragrant gel | 1 | 2021-05-01 |

**Table 2** with `PRIMARY KEY (campaign_id, sku, report_date)`

| campaign_id | sku | product_name | orders | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3516 | Product 1 | 1 | 2021-05-01 |
| 1 | 87218 | Product 2 | 2 | 2021-05-01 |
| 1 | 4478 | Product 3 | 4 | 2021-05-01 |

I want to JOIN them and GROUP by `campaign_id` and `date` to get next result:

| campaign_id | impressions | orders | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | 7 | 2021-05-01 |

I wrote SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW result.all_stats AS
SELECT
    t1.campaign_id,
    t1.report_date,
    sum(t1.clicks) AS clicks,
    sum(t2.orders) AS orders,
FROM
    result.table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN result.table2 t2 ON t1.campaign_id = t2.campaign_id
    AND t1.report_date = t2.report_date
GROUP BY
    t1.campaign_id,
    t1.report_date;
```

But it actually returns:

| campaign_id | impressions | orders | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 24 | 21 | 2021-05-01 |

So script joined result 3 times because 3 rows in table 2. I need to **GROUP first table** by `campaign_id` + `date` and **GROUP second table** by `campaign_id` + `date` and then **JOIN them**. How to fix it?

Comment: `select ... from (select ... GROUP BY ...) t1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT ... GROUP BY ...) t2 ON t1.x = t2.y`

Answer (score 1):

here is one way :

```
SELECT
    t1.campaign_id,
    t1.report_date,
    sum(t1.clicks) AS clicks,
    t2.orders AS orders,
FROM
    result.table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN lateral(
        select sum(t2.orders) orders
        from result.table2 t2 
        where t1.campaign_id = t2.campaign_id
        AND t1.report_date = t2.report_date
    ) t2 on true
GROUP BY
    t1.campaign_id,
    t1.report_date,
    t2.orders
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest aggregating *before* joining:

```
SELECT campaign_id, report_date, c.clicks, o.orders
FROM (SELECT campaign_id, report_date, sum(clicks) as clicks
      FROM result.table1 t1
      GROUP BY campaign_id, report_date
     ) c LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT campaign_id, report_date, SUM(orders) as orders
      FROM result.table2 t2
      GROUP BY campaign_id, report_date
     ) o
     USING (campaign_id, report_date);
```

Note:  You might want to consider `FULL JOIN` to take care of situations where you have orders for a campaign that are on a date with no clicks.

Comment: Thanks! 
Yes, you're right, I need `FULL JOIN`. 
Now when I've orders but don't have clicks, I see row with only orders - campaign_id and report_date is null for these rows. How to fix it?

Comment: @hsadik . . . Note that the `select` does not qualify `campaign_id` and `report_date` and the query uses `using`.   This should work with a `full join` (although the `clicks` and `orders` values may be `NULL`).

Comment: I found examples: row in table with clicks (campaign = 1, report_date = '2021-04-30') doesnt exist. And row in table with orders (campaign = 1, report_date = '2021-04-30')  exists. So, with full join campaign_id and report_date will be NULL